# Is is possible to divide page control dots into two lines?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scrollview, uipagecontrol

I got a number of dots of page control, obviously it's too long and beyond the screen width.

Set `pagecontrol=[[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(108, 500, 100, 50)];` to contraint its width, but looks not work.

Is it possible to divid these dots into two lines or even more?

[image]

Comment: If you have a page control which goes beyond the screen width, then you're using it wrong. In that case, you should use a label like `10/50`.

Comment: Your saying sounds a good alternative. But I think dots look nicer than digits. :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the Tasks `UIPageControl` offers, there's no easy way to implement multi-line page control. Also, the `sizeForNumberOfPages:` method, there's no break mode or anything to allow you to control the number of dots per line, it will most likely just return `X * dotSize`, where X is the number of pages.

Also, the note `On iPhone and iPod touch, about 20 page control dots fit on the screen before they are clipped` says that there's no built in method to create multi-line page control.

You can of course always create a custom class, but I REALLY wouldn't suggest doing that. The user won't expect (or like) a multi-line page control anyway.

You can use something like `10 of 50` like the iBooks app uses.